# Symlink not working

Tags: linux, symlink

I have two folders, `/test/opt` and `/test2/opt`.

I want to create a symbolic link so that when application will write something to `/test/opt` it will go to `/test2/opt`.

I tried creating a symlink using `ln -s /test2/opt /test/opt`. But the thing happening is: it is creating the `opt` directory inside `/test/opt` and it's getting linked to `/test2/opt`.

Don't know what's happening here. `test` has other directory as well.
Tried adding `/` on both sides one side of source `/` target but it's not happening.

Comment: If `/test/opt` already exists, `ln` won't be able to put a symlink to `/test2/opt` at that location without removing it.

Comment: You want to say vice versa? So what should I do?  My /test/ is separate mount where now no space available so I want to redirect new files from /test/opt to this new folder (/test2/opt) which is under different mount where I have space .

Comment: yeah, point is, destination of a symlink can't already exist.

Comment: Ok so it will delete /test2 & /test2/opt and then will run script.

Comment: but just as `ln` won't remove an exising directory by default, it also won't recursively create them.  Just like if you wanted to create any other type of  file in `/test2`, if you want to create a symlink in `/test2`, that directory must exist first.

Comment: But if opt is not present inside test2 before running code then red color pop up comes after /test/opt --> /test2/opt when we do ls - lrt test .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are seeing is the expected behavior. `ln -s` behaves similarly to `mv`, `cp`, and `ln`. If the second argument refers to an existing directory, `mv file dir`, moves the file into `dir`, `cp file dir` copies the file into `dir`, and `ln file dir` (with or without `-s`) creates the link into `dir`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not working as `/test/opt` already exists, remove it then run:

```
ln -s /test2/opt /test/opt
```

Comment: So I am confused here /test/opt is my source and /test2/opt is my target so when I will do ls -lrt test, I should see test -->/test2/opt.Is there any option where if I don't want to delete /test/opt before running script.

Comment: `/test/opt` can't be _both_ a symlink and a directory.

Comment: Ok now I got it, I will delete source i.e /test/opt and will run script ln -s /test2/opt /test/opt so it will create symlink inside /test which will point to /test2/opt. So when I will do ls - lrt /test it will show opt -->/test2/opt

Comment: Hi Now it worked , I have one more folder where it is mount , e.g. /tmp is separate mount and I want to create symlink for this /tmp so when I will do ls -lrt / , it wshould show me tmp --> /test2/tmp